# System.InvalidOperationException. The specified type was not recognized error deserializing XML

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to deserialize the following XML using C#:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <out:response xmlns:out="http://AccountService" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <fault>
        <faultcode>0</faultcode>
        <faultstring>RESPONSE_OK</faultstring>
        <detail>Successful reply.</detail>
      </fault>
      <serviceResponse xsi:type="out:GetAccountInfoResponse">
        <accountInfo>
          <personId>123</personId>
          <account>
            <accountId>1</accountId>
            <accountNo>11</accountNo>
          </account>
          <account>
            <accountId>2</accountId>
            <accountNo>22</accountNo>
          </account>
        </accountInfo>
      </serviceResponse>
    </out:response>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My class structure:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Envelope
    {

        private EnvelopeBody bodyField;

        public EnvelopeBody Body
        {
            get
            {
                return this.bodyField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.bodyField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public partial class EnvelopeBody
    {

        private response responseField;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://AccountService")]
        public response response
        {
            get
            {
                return this.responseField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.responseField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://AccountService")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://AccountService", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class response
    {

        private fault faultField;

        private serviceResponse serviceResponseField;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "")]
        public fault fault
        {
            get
            {
                return this.faultField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.faultField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "")]
        public serviceResponse serviceResponse
        {
            get
            {
                return this.serviceResponseField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.serviceResponseField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class fault
    {

        private byte faultcodeField;

        private string faultstringField;

        private string detailField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public byte faultcode
        {
            get
            {
                return this.faultcodeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.faultcodeField = value;
            }
        }

        public string faultstring
        {
            get
            {
                return this.faultstringField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.faultstringField = value;
            }
        }

        public string detail
        {
            get
            {
                return this.detailField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.detailField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class serviceResponse
    {

        private serviceResponseAccountInfo accountInfoField;

        public serviceResponseAccountInfo accountInfo
        {
            get
            {
                return this.accountInfoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.accountInfoField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class serviceResponseAccountInfo
    {

        private byte personIdField;

        private serviceResponseAccountInfoAccount[] accountField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public byte personId
        {
            get
            {
                return this.personIdField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.personIdField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("account")]
        public serviceResponseAccountInfoAccount[] account
        {
            get
            {
                return this.accountField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.accountField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class serviceResponseAccountInfoAccount
    {

        private byte accountIdField;

        private byte accountNoField;

        public byte accountId
        {
            get
            {
                return this.accountIdField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.accountIdField = value;
            }
        }

        public byte accountNo
        {
            get
            {
                return this.accountNoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.accountNoField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Deserialization produces the error:

> The specified type was not recognized: name='GetAccountInfoResponse'.

Answer (score 2):

When you defining specific types in xml schema:

```
<serviceResponse xsi:type="out:GetAccountInfoResponse">
```

You must specify it in the XmlTypeAttribute of **serviceResponse** class, this way

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://AccountService",TypeName = "GetAccountInfoResponse")]
```

Comment: i've specified but accountInfo is null